# forcing one function to complete execution before another function on button click

Tags: c#, javascript, buttonclick

Here i am trying to execute two functions i.e. one javascript and one c# code on a single button click.The problem is both the functions are executing simultaneously.Here are my functions:

Javascript function

```
 function exportCharts() {
            var exportFormat = 'JPG';
            initiateExport = true;
            for (var chartRef in FusionCharts.items) {
                if (FusionCharts.items[chartRef].exportChart) {
                    document.getElementById("linkToExportedFile").innerHTML = "Exporting...";
                    FusionCharts.items[chartRef].exportChart({ "exportFormat": exportFormat });
                }
                else {

                    document.getElementById("linkToExportedFile").innerHTML = "Please wait till the chart completes rendering...";
                }
            }
        }
```

c# code:

```
 protected void imgBTNExportPPT_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                PredictExportToPPT objOExporttoPPT = new PredictExportToPPT();

                PredictionModel();

                string reportNames = ObjCommon.GetBIReportNames("Prediction", "Report");
                reportNames += ObjCommon.GetBIReportNames("Prediction", "Table");

                objOExporttoPPT.ExportToPPTPredict(ObjPredictInputParameter, reportNames, ObjSharedEntities.PredictTableData);

                string itemname = "PPTOutput.pptx";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "pptx";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + itemname + "");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(DataTemplate.PPTOutputTemplateFilePath)));
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

            }
            catch (Exception exceptionMessage)
            {
                throw (exceptionMessage);
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```

Button click code

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBTNExportPPT" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" border="0" OnClientClick="return exportCharts()" OnClick="imgBTNExportPPT_Click" />
```

If i try to use **System.Threading.Thread.Sleep** for the c# code,the javascript code is executing first but not completely.It waits till the execution of c# code and finally both the outputs are generated simultaneously.I want it to happen one after the other. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which one do you want to happen first?

Comment: i want the javascript code to execute first

Answer (score 2):

**I have tested it it is working**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBTNExportPPT" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" border="0" OnClientClick="exportReport()" OnClick="imgBTNExportPPT_Click" />

   <script>
            function exportReport() {
              exportCharts();
             __doPostBack("imgBTNExportPPT","");
         }
    </script>
```

If you are using master page, then:

replace

```
__doPostBack("imgBTNExportPPT","");
```

with

```
__doPostBack("ctl00$MainContent$imgBTNExportPPT", "");
```

Comment: sorry that's not working..on button click directly its going to the c# code..javascript code is not executing

Comment: Just remove the `OnClick` property entirely, then it will work.

Comment: still no luck..after removing onclick the page itself is reloading..none of the two functions are working

Comment: hello everyone tried everything mentioned above but still no luck.The javascript code is executing first but in the middle of the execution only the c# code is showing its output.Also i would like to mention that the javascript code takes some time to execute completely.A progress bar indicating the progress comes.Using the above techniques,the c# code executes when the progress bar is at 10% itself.

Comment: now i tried giving System.Threading.Thread.Sleep for c# code..the thing is it is working but very rarely like 1 in 15 times.I need 3 images to be generated from the javascript code but only 2 or 1 is coming.And most of the time it doesn't come atall till i click something on the popup which comes because of c# code.